# Sequence of holomorphic functions converging on compact sets with $f_n(D) \subset U$ implies $f(D) \subset U$ or $f(z) = c$ for $c \in \partial U$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D$ be an open connected set and $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of holomorphic functions on $D$ that converge uniformly to a holomorphic function $f$ on all compact subsets of $D$. Suppose that $f_n(D) \subset U$ for all $n$. Show that either $f(D) \subset U$ or there is a $c \in \partial U$ such that $f(z) = c$ for all $z \in D$.

First I supposed that $f$ was not a constant function. Then I suppose that there is a $w \in D$ such that $f(w) \notin \overline{U}$ By the open mapping theorem, I can take a small ball around this point. Consider the closure of this ball. Then the pullback of this ball under $f$ is a closed set in $D$. Then I hope to use uniform convergence on compact sets to show that for $n$ large enough $f_n(D) \not\subset U$ which would be a contradiction.

I don't feel confident with this approach. Also, this homework was given in a problem set that uses the Schwarz Reflection Principle as well as [Caratheodory's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_theorem_(conformal_mapping)) so perhaps I should make use of these theorems.

Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that there is $p\in D$ such that $f(p)\notin U$. Since $f(p)$ is the limit of $f_n(p)\in U$ you must have that $f(p)\in\overline{U}$.

If $f\not\equiv f(p)$, then by [Hurwitz's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)) (which proof is just an exercise using the [argument principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle)), if we take a neighborhood of $p$ inside $D$, then for all large enough $n$ the functions $f_n(z)-f(p)$ will have solutions in that neighborhood. But this is not possible, since $f_n(z)\in U$ and $f(p)\notin U$.

Therefore $f\equiv f(p)$.

Comment: So you are applying the Hurwitz’s theorem to the sequence $f_n(z) - f(p)$, right?  Noting that the limit function $f(z) - f(p)$ has at least one solution, this implies that for n large enough $f_n(z)$ will equal $f(p)$ for some $z$. And of course, this is a contradiction. Is this correct?

Comment: @NicholasRoberts Yes, that is the use of Hurwitz's.

Answer (score 0):

This follows immediately from Open Mapping Theorem for analytic functions. Clearly $f(D)$ is contained in the closed unit ball. If $f$ is non-constant then it maps open sets to open sets to open sets and any open subset of the closed unit disk is contained in the open unit disk